# blender normal map white shining

Tags: rendering

why my normal maps is shining white? I have no idea why.I took a high strength level to show you my result. Its very confusing to see the white glow if i plug in my normal map. I also tried the bump shader same problem.
I using Blender 2.8. render eevee
[image: without normal map]
[image: with normal map]
[image: diffuse]
[image: normal]
[image]
[image: inverted]

Hi guys i added one more picture. I have a wiered looking reflection. The only object with this color is in the inside of the building how does the reflection appear on the glas?
[image: wrong reflection]
[image: inside]

Comment: it's hard to understand what is your problem, do you mean your texture is much brighter that what it is without any normal map? maybe share your file (with the images packed): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: added 1 more picture. The white glow is within the joints. Normaly they should be darker with a slightly depth

Comment: Looks like your normal map is flipped vertically. Also are you using DirectX normal map as OpenGL normal map?

Comment: How to flip the map and what is directx and opengl normal map? There is a different? :O

Comment: weird because if I open your b&w picture with CrazyBump then make a normal map, it works fine, it's not inverted like yours

Comment: useing materialize for maps i found some shader setup to  invert it. Maybe looks a little bit better

Comment: [invert the green channel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110748/11431)

Comment: Downloaded your picture and looked inside channels. You are indeed using DirectX normal map. See the link Bithur gave, that's the solution. Or convert it inside photoshop.

Comment: To give it a bit more depth you should add a ambient occlusion map as well. Normal maps that looks like they are lit from beneath are directx.

Comment: how to add the ambient occlusion map?

Comment: Found it. Thx for your help guys!

Comment: Hi guys i added 2 more pictures. Maybe you cna help me again. Why the blie reflection shines through the wall?