# Why rendering black areas in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Thanks for reading this.

When rendering I get black areas using Cycles. It happens with path tracing and also branch tracing. I tried to deactivate all different light sources but problem still persists. I have checked the geometry and that seems OK too.

Blender version 2.92

I have included the blend file in the following link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10B9H-IZI_4YW23S_orMQxuBohhXw6plb/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much for helping out.

[image]Best regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Normal and displacements are connected in the wrong way, you need a Normal map node and a displacement Node, also your normal image needs to have a Non color on the color space.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back so quickly. Really appreciated! Regards!

Comment: @Emir I'm at the phone right now so I can't download the file to check materials and textures... but is it intentional that you've plugged the _Alpha_ output of the texture into the _Color_ input of the _Normal Map_ node?

Comment: You are right, wrong right side screenshot, sorry I was testing the texture and did not notice the screen, I will edit that later

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Emir's answer, some more findings:

You have created the bunkers with the *Boolean Modifier*. To get a smooth result you should enable *Auto Smooth* and *Shade Smooth* (right-click the object in *Object Mode*)

[image: no auto smooth]<sup>No auto smooth</sup>

[image: with auto smooth enabled]<sup>Auto smooth enabled</sup>

For the material you need to add the *Normal Conversation* group before the *Normal Map* node that you had forgotten to add. This will remove the black area as seen on Emir's screenshot at the inner of the concrete bunker.

[image: missing nodes]

You have also node groups named "NodeGroup", "NodeGroup.001", "NodeGroup.002" which all do the same as the "Normal Conversation" node does. They just use an *Invert* node instead of a *Math Subtract* node You might have accidentally duplicated the groups.

Comment: Why do you need the normal conversion node?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati It's because the used image is in DirectX normal format but Blender uses OpenGL normal format. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100017/directx-vs-opengl-normal-maps