# I'm Having a normal map issue with a model i downloaded

Tags: normals

[image]

I downloaded a ripped model but the normal map that came with it causes a weird shading issue on the model and i'm pretty new to modelling so i have no idea what the issue could be

Edit: the blend file and textures https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2924062cd60f4de6f1313bff8fa5863b20220113132230/f865a0ecdac79de288f857ca3b8c7e0520220113132305/48c295

this is how the normal map looks like :

[image]

Comment: share the blend file with the textures, maybe that way we can try to look for errors overselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This red normal map is a Unity-optimized normal map. It's compressed and you need to unpack it with the [UnpackNormal](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Normal-Unpack-Node.html) function.

According to [this Unity forum thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/packing-unpacking-normals-looking-for-indepth-info.256863/), the `UnpackNormal` function looks like this:

```c#
inline fixed3 UnpackNormalDXT5nm (fixed4 packednormal)
{
   fixed3 normal;
   normal.xy = packednormal.wy * 2 - 1;
#if defined(SHADER_API_FLASH)
   // Flash does not have efficient saturate(), and dot() seems to require an extra register.
   normal.z = sqrt(1 - normal.x*normal.x - normal.y * normal.y);
#else
   normal.z = sqrt(1 - saturate(dot(normal.xy, normal.xy)));
#endif
   return normal;
}
     
inline fixed3 UnpackNormal(fixed4 packednormal)
{
#if (defined(SHADER_API_GLES) || defined(SHADER_API_GLES3)) && defined(SHADER_API_MOBILE)
   return packednormal.xyz * 2 - 1;
#else
   return UnpackNormalDXT5nm(packednormal);
#endif
}
```

> **Compression**
>
> As for compression, desktop platforms will attempt to
> store it as DXT5nm format. That means that it takes the **red component**
> of the texture and stores it in the **alpha channel**, then **wipes the red
> and the blue channel**.
>
> Normal maps are pretty sensitive so you want the best compression you
> can get. DXT5 compression stores its R/G/B/A channels with 5/6/5/8
> bits of accuracy, respectively. Meaning that the **Green and Alpha
> channels** store values with higher precision than the Red and Blue
> channels.
>
> However, because a tangent space normal map should be a
> normalized/unit vector (a vector with a magnitude - length - of 1.0)
> and the Z component (blue channel) is never negative, you can use the
> code defined in UnpackNormalDXT5nm() to **reconstruct the Z component
> (blue channel)** if you know the values of the other two. Which means
> you can store the 3 component vector using just 2 components in the
> texture map, meaning you use the two highest precision channels in the
> texture to store it.
>
> This is pretty standard behaviour for desktop/console normal map
> storage.
>
> For mobile platforms, that code's a little too expensive to run just
> for the sake of higher quality normal maps, so for mobile platforms
> the normal map gets stored as a regular RGB texture, without the
> channel swapping. That makes unpacking it a lot simpler (simply
> **unpacking it from 0.0 - 1.0 range into -1.0 - 1.0 range by doing
> `fixed3 normal = normalMap.rgb * 2 - 1;`**).

**Unpack Normal In Blender**

With this knowledge, you can create a node group with some *Math* and *Map Range* nodes to calculate the Z value from X and Y. Because it's a DirectX normal map you need additionally to invert the Y value to get Blender's OpenGL format ([DirectX vs. OpenGL normal maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100017/107598)).

**Node Group Unpack Normal Map (Unity)**
[image: unpack normal map (unity)]

**Shader Nodes For The Material**
[image: shader nodes]
*(Disclaimer: Not sure if *Specular* and *Roughness* are correctly wired.)*

In the *Properties* of the *Image Texture* node, make sure the *Alpha* mode of the image is set to `Channel Packed`. And in the *N-Panel > Options tab* or in *Material Properties > Settings* set the *Blend Mode* and *Shadow Mode* to `Alpha Hashed` to enable transparency for *Eevee* and *Material Preview* shading mode.

[image: n-panel]

**Test Render (Eevee)**
[image: model front]

[image: model back]