# How to use Blender for converting DX normal-files to GL?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

How can I can use Blender to load normal maps made the DirectX way and convert them into openGL format?

EDIT: I got the linked node setup to work, thanks for the link. Also, the visual example of how GL files look lit from above while as DirectX files look lit from below was really useful.

Comment: I vote to reopen because you can do it inside Blender in shader nodes. All you have to do is separate RGB, invert G channel, then combine them back.

Comment: Seconded, this is the only functional difference between OpenGL and DX normal maps, the inverted Y/G channel.

Comment: As Crantisz wrote, the question is answered here: [DirectX vs. OpenGL normal maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100017/107598)