# Normal map creates seams

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I made this simple model of a ring in blender then textured it in substance painter.
And I am having an issue when I use the normal map, making the seams very obvious.
Any way to fix this?

[image: without normal map]

[image: with normal map]

[image]
[Here is the blender project with the texture if necessary](https://mega.nz/file/LIgW0LzC#FUk5lWpFguBcpu9cECjhS9pleILU6mlAZRcwFHeytgk)

Comment: See the second (not mine) answer on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93398/visible-seams-on-tangent-normal-maps. You need to set the color space on the normal map image texture node to non-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sazerac mentioned, you need to set your Normal Map image to non-color space. In keeping with this, however, I would also suggest using a Math Node set to subtract instead of an Invert node (for DX to OpenGL conversion, I assume?), just to make sure things stay in non-color space, and there are no unnecessary back-and-forth conversions (as a matter of good practice). Your Roughness and Metallic maps should also be set to non-color, however, because you are using the same image for your Roughness and BaseColor, I have adapted the graph with a RGB to BW node going into the Roughness (because changing the color space of one of the images changes both, and setting both to non-color would make the BaseColor look "washed out").

[image: Ring]